# how i will parse this ret in python 3.6

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.6

I have this return JSON string below. I would like to parse it with python 3.6, but I don't know how. I'm a beginner in python.

Can someone help me with this.

```
[{
    "src": "125.167.217.133",
    "dpt": "80",
    "city": "Balikpapan",
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/id.svg",
    "to_char": "26-04-2018"
},
{
    "src": "93.104.209.73",
    "dpt": "80",
    "city": null,
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/de.svg",
    "to_char": "26-04-2018"
},
{
    "src": "125.167.217.133",
    "dpt": "443",
    "city": "Balikpapan",
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/id.svg",
    "to_char": "26-04-2018"
}]
```

Comment: Where did you get it? Is it JSON?

Comment: this is a ret of sqlacademy query transformed of dict to json.

Comment: i put bellow the formatted ret image

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

Comment: sorry, i forget put that i need parse it with jinja2

Comment: @DMR: You should parse it before it reaches the template.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of objects in what looks like JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) for short.

My guess is that you received this data from some JavaScript source?

I can only assume you're trying to read values from the keys in your JSON objects.

```
import json
# load your JSON string and into this variable
json_string = ''
data = json.loads(json_string)
for item in items:
   print(items['src'])
```

This will print all of values in your JSON data structure that have the key `src`. Note, that you can replace `src` with any key in the object.
If this is not what you were looking for, please make your question more specific.

Comment: sorry, i forget put that i need parse it with jinja2